# Fonte não aceita acentuação

Tags: html, css

Fala pessoal, estou utilizando uma fonte personalizada, para isso uso o @fontface no CSS.
Estou tendo problemas em colocar acentuação, quando coloco ele fica assim, siga o link da imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu poderia fazer ?

Comment: Eu não entendo muito de fontes, mas receio que a resposta seja: "nada"... :( Ou uma fonte dá suporte a um determinado conjunto de caracteres ou ela não dá. Não dá pra exibir japonês no Arial, Times New Roman, Courier... Da mesma forma, se o autor da fonte não incluiu caracteres acentuados, ou os incluiu com proporções "erradas", ou - como parece ser o caso - não há letras acentuadas maiúsculas, só minúsculas, a única saída parece ser trocar de fonte.

Comment: P.S. Experimente escrever o `Ê` não como um [caractere pré-composto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character), mas como um par de [caracteres combinantes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) (`E\u0302`). 99% de chance de ficar feio, mas pode funcionar...

Comment: Estou tendo o mesmo problema que você e vejo sentido no que o @mgibsonbr falou. Os caracteres de um tipo de fonte são determinados para um tipo especifico de saída. Como as vezes o público daquela fonte é local, não há a preocupação de inserir caracteres latinos por exemplo.

Comment: Vou ter que trocar a fonte mesmo. tentei o caracteres combinantes e não funcionou. obrigado @mgibsonbr.

Você recomenda algum site pra escolher as fontes?

Comment: @AndersonMenezes Não, eu sempre uso as fontes "normais" mesmo, não conheço outras... Ou, é claro, as fontes [Liberation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_fonts) hehe (fontes com licença GNU GPL :P)

Comment: Vou procurar pra ver se acho alguma semelhante.

Comment: google.com/fonts

Answer (score 5):

Isto não é um problema de CSS. O problema se encontra no set de caracteres da fonte. A solução seria encontrar uma versão internacionalizada da fonte pretendida, ou usar uma outra que lhe agrade e tenha o set completo para a língua utilizada.

Uma possível (e trabalhosa) solução seria você baixar a fonte, e usar um editor de caracteres (há alguns gratuitos e outros pagos no mercado). A maior parte desses programas permite que você copie partes de um caractere para outros, assim você poderia combinar os acentos e letras desejados.

> Neste segundo caso, é muito importante ler a licença original da fonte desejada para ver se modificações e posterior publicação são permitidos.

Answer (score 1):

É isso mesmo tem fonte que não tem suporte para a nossa língua. Quando se trata
títulos ou texto pequeno eu resolvo assim:

converto o texto em curva e adiciono a acentuação manualmente, ç - ^ `´, etc....
agora se for texto longo não tem jeito só trocando de fonte.

Antônio Carlos

Answer (score -5):

Na verdade a fonte em questão suporta, veja que ela exibe o carácter em questão.

Portanto, basta que você use o type correto.

Para isso na primeira linha código use a função setlocale do PHP

setlocale(LC_ALL,"pt_BR");

Comment: Para mais detalhes http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setlocale.php